# How to get starting date from week number

Tags: php, date, datetime

Getting week number this format :

```
$weeknumber = date('W', strtotime('10-02-2015'));
```

How to get starting date from this weeknumber.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

you need to change like this `strtotime('10-02-2015'))`

```
$date_string = "2012-10-18";
$weeknumber =  date("W", strtotime($date_string));

//get the date from week number
```

[isodate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)

```
$gendate = new DateTime();
$gendate->setISODate(2013,$weeknumber ,4); //year , week num , day
echo $gendate->format('d-m-Y'); //"prints"  26-12-2013
```

Comment: Coding Cracker,  thanks reply. am already getting week number but need dates from this week number.

Comment: Coding Cracker, thanks reply. But this method not working another way without year and day. Only using week number.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
  echo $weeknumber = date('W', strtotime('18-10-2012'));
  $gendate = new DateTime();
  $gendate->setISODate(2015,$weeknumber,4); //year , week num , day
  echo $gendate->format('d-m-Y'); //"prints"
```

Comment: This is the exact same code as OP already have only with a different date!

Comment: Please Tell me what you want it give the week number

Comment: Priya786, How to get dates from this week number. any idea!

Comment: @priya786 I don't want anything, OP wants something, I just said that this is the exact same code as OP already have and it doesn't add any *value* here

Comment: Now check this it will give you the date

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `strtotime()` and `date()` functions with `DateTime` class. It can be simply done without them, and with only `DateTime`, like:

```php
$date = new DateTime('10-02-2015');
$date->setISODate($date->format('o'), $date->format('W'));
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/294982)</kbd>